# C++: How do you calculate the sums of columns in comma separated values?

Tags: c++, json, parsing, csv, sum

I'm dealing with a slightly specific problem. I have a program which grabs tables from the web in JSON format and converts them to CSVs. The tables are dynamic in size and include a header row with text. One table might look like:

```
DataCode,AreaName,AreaID,Population
G1000,Billford,15,21000
G1001,Millville,18,21000
```

Assuming I don't know how big the array is going to be, I would like to be able to take the sum of ONLY the population statistic. (I will have the header for the column for which I want the data stored in a variable, in this case "population" but it changes dynamically as well.)

When consolidating multiple tables, I also have the issue that duplicate entries are difficult to remove. For example a combined table may look like:

```
DataCode,AreaName,AreaID,Population
G1000,Billford,15,21000
G1001,Millville,18,21000
DataCode,AreaName,AreaID,Population
G1003,Brinton,21,26000
G1004,Nixon,24,12000
```

I'm mystified by how to create a function that can take a table of any size in CSV or JSON format, and take the sum of only the numbers in a given column.

Comment: If you have MS Excel installed, which can read CSV, you would simply highlight the column you want, and your sum is displayed in the status bar :)

Comment: Do you have a CSV reader?  If so, then just retrieve the Population column and sum it until there are no more rows.  If not, search this site for examples of it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use one of the solutions to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c), and then sum up the 4th column. Non numerical input will just be zero when you try to convert it with `atoi` or `strtol`.